# Is it possible to get data of two different rows in one row (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table whereby the data of the same customer id is in a new row:

```
order_id | cust_id | order_date                 | menu_item 
------------------------------------------------------------
order1   | cust1   | January 19, 2020, 1:00 PM  |           
         | cust1   |                            | food_A
```

Is it possible to get a one row of the data like below:

```
order_id | cust_id | order_date                 | menu_item 
------------------------------------------------------------
order1   | cust1   | January 19, 2020, 1:00 PM  | food_A
```

I tried joining but then i get the same as the table where it prints out two data instead of one. Might be my join isn't correct. Appreciate the help. thanks

```
select s.cust_id, s.menu_item from tableA s inner join tableA t on s.cust_id = t.cust_id
```

Comment: `Might be my join isn't correct` ... what is your join supposed to be doing?  You are doing a self join, but it isn't clear why.  Please include sample input/output data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, assuming the missing values be `NULL`, you may just aggregate by `order_id` and `cust_id` and then take the max of the other two columns:

```sql
SELECT
    order_id,
    cust_id,
    MAX(order_date) AS order_date,
    MAX(menu_item)  AS menu_item
FROM tableA
GROUP BY
    order_id,
    cust_id;
```

Comment: aa okay. yeah i think i got it now. thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: is there another way to do this @TimBiegeleisen? seems like this takes a long time to load if the data is large

Comment: The correct action here would be to fix your data such that you don't even need to aggregate this way.

Comment: yeah, seems like that's the best way. thanks @TimBiegeleisen